# Multiple On-submit is showing duplicate warning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, ecmascript-6, onsubmit

I have used two npm package in my form. One is working form validation and another is working for mail sending. Both are functionally working fine but showing a warning in the console

```
<ValidationForm
    id="contactForm"
    onSubmit={(e, formData, inputs,) => {
        e.preventDefault();
    }}
    onSubmit={this.handleForm}
>
```

**Warning msg**:
 `Line 170:  No duplicate props allowed  react/jsx-no-duplicate-props`

Comment: Why don't you just add {this.handleForm} in the first onSubmit property? Why do you need two onSubmit properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is exactly as the message states "you are not allowed to have duplicate props".

If you want multiple actions to take  place on submit then you should just merge the two handlers.

```
<ValidationForm
    id="contactForm"
    onSubmit={(e, formData, inputs,) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.handleForm(formData);
    }}
>
```